# Bypass bios password on Toshiba Satellite C55Dt-A5106?

Tags: laptop, bios, passwords, bypass, toshiba-hard-drive

Soon as I turn it on it goes from the Toshiba  logo screen to a blue box asking for a password.  Is there a way by this or any way to get some kind of menu ? Just want the windows to load so I can restore to factory settings.

Comment: [This](http://findpassword.net/reset-toshiba-satellite-bios-password/) is your best bet.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable/reset power-on password in Toshiba satellite laptop C55DT-A5106](http://superuser.com/questions/1061520/how-to-disable-reset-power-on-password-in-toshiba-satellite-laptop-c55dt-a5106)

Answer (score -1):

No, there is no bypassing it.

If there would be a way to bypass it, it would be pretty useless. *What sense would a password protection make, when you don't have to enter it?*

You can remove or change the password in the BIOS once you entered it.

Comment: Not true, depends on make and model if it can be reset or not.